# D3: append circle does not work - must be missing something

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Edit: This question can be simplified, and here it goes:

I am adding tryign to add a "circle" to a SVG. Turns out, the added circle is added to the DOM, but not to the svg, and is also not fitted to the scale.

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <g class="x axis" transform="translate(0,200)" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" font-size="10px">
    <g class="y axis" transform="translate(200,0)" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" font-size="10px">
    <circle fill="#008000" r="10" cy="56" cx="56">
    <circle fill="#008000" r="10" cy="56" cx="128">
    <circle fill="#008000" r="10" cy="56" cx="164">
</svg>
<circle fill="#ffff00" r="10" cy="344" cx="340.4"></circle>
```

What I am trying to accomplish can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/eNe3U/13/

In jsfiddle it works! This is how I want it!

It starts with 3 green circles from a data array from index 0 to 2. Then it gets updated using another dataset, index 1 to 3. This is how the first circle is removed and the last one is added in D3(, right?)

1. moving + changing to red
2. adding a yellow circle
3. removing the first (green) circle. Perfect!

Now, when I try to use this in my visual studio project, adding the yellow circle does not work. I've been stuck for quite a while, maybe I have overlooked something or not fully understood the ways of D3.

So, here is my code: http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/66925872

pretty much the same as in the fiddle, just separated in 2 functions. Where is the bug?

```
 circle.enter().append("circle") // .data(mydata2, function(d) { return d.i; })
      .transition().delay(1000).duration(500)
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
      .attr("r", 10).attr("fill", "yellow");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

circle.enter().... doesn't circle point to the svg circle element? shouldn't it be svg.enter().append("circle") so that you append the circle to the svg?

Comment: good point. Trying this right now. As I am stepping through the code in Firebug execution aborts exactly at that line svg.enter().append("circle"). This is happening in a "update3D"-function, where the svg is declared as "var svg = d3.select("#d3");". This svg already exists on the page at this point. I suspect that this might be the problem somehow...!?

Comment: how do I get hold of an existing svg?

Comment: Yeah I would just make the svg object accesible to both functions by making it global. If you want to have a bit more control you could namespace the whole thing to avoid collision

Comment: yes. To be honest, I am struggling a bit with this though (and spent more time on this that I'd like to admit). Most examples that I've found just leave the svg element etc. lying around within the <script> tags... Would you be so kind and make a small example in a jsfiddle, as a separate answer maybe? That would be awesome!

Comment: Sure here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/zk7fC/1/  I added a bit more to it in order to exemplify update and exit. In order to keep everything isolated I created an anonymous function that automatically calls its self. Everything is contained with in it so nothing should escape.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Meanwhile I have powered through and made my code work anyway. I will however study your code as soon as I have recovered from this. So much to learn...

Comment: Cool! great to hear you managed to pull through. Best of luck